# c++ pass a curried function to a function which receives a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, currying

```
void foo(void (*)(long v)) {}

auto makeBar(long baz) {
    return [=](long v) {
        std::cout << "hello from closure " << baz;
    };
}


int main() {
   auto  bar = makeBar(2);
   foo(bar);
   return 0;
}
```

Hi,

I'm trying to do the above.
Essentially create a curried function makeBar which receives a parameter baz.
then instantiate it and pass the result to function foo.

the following does not compile. Specifically the call to foo(bar).
If I remove the capture [=] it compiles, but then I can't use baz within the curry.

How can this be done?

Comment: not exactly. I forgot to mention that I don't have access to foo's impl or definition (not owned by me)

Comment: For Currying you can use `std::bind`

Comment: *I don't have access to foo's impl or definition* Then you can't pass capturing lambdas.