# Simplest case of currying with a lambda is illegal

Tags: c++, lambda, currying

The textbook functional programming introduction example "return a function with a curried parameter" in C++ does not compile for me:

```
// return a function x(v) parameterized with b, which tells if v > b
bool (*greater(int))(int b) 
{
    return [b](int v) { return v > b; };
}
```

It says that identifier `b` in the capture `[b]` is undefined. I know that I'm being naive here, but where is my error?

EDIT: as @some-programmer-dude pointed out correctly, the function signature is wrong.

*`greater` is a function accepting an `int b` returning ( a pointer `*` to a function accepting an `(int)` returning a `bool` ).*

```
// return a function x(v) parameterized with b, which tells if v > b
bool (*greater(int b))(int) 
{
    return [b](int v) { return v > b; };
}
```

This of course does not remove the original question which all three replies answered correctly.

Comment: Only lambdas **without capture** can be cast into a C style function pointer. Lambdas with capture are actually classes with data members (one for each capture). In your case you have one capture (`b`).

Comment: Your declaration for returning a function pointer is wrong (the b should beside the first int) `bool (*greater(int b))(int v)`.  Some `using` statements to simplify that type might make that clerer. But even so, you can't convert a lambda into a function pointer (apart from the most trivial of lambda's with not special features).

Comment: can't convert a **capturing** lambda into a function pointer. Plain lambdas do just fine in that regard.

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128124/c-pass-a-curried-function-to-a-function-which-receives-a-pointer) , [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer)

Comment: @JasonLiam this question is regarding the computer science concept of currying, and not only the technical issue of converting lambdas to fucntion pointers. The links you posted do not really address this issue (the answers focus on the technical issue). Please consider to re-open the question.

Comment: @wohlstad The fundamental problem is the same which is that "a capturing lambda cannot be converted into a function pointer".This question can be answered by any of the dupes. That is the main thing here.Just because OP mentioned currying doesn't mean the problem isn't due to a capturing lambda. You can add many different terms in the question like `templates`, `inference` etc but that will still mean that the problem is due to a capturing lambda which is explained in any of the dupes.I am sure there are even more dupes for this but I think the current one is enough. Feel free to suggest more.

Comment: @JasonLiam I believe that although the core of StackOverflow is to supply immediate answers to technical questions, people can benefit from some broader context and overview of relevant issues. I think currying and closure are such issues and the OP is clearly interested in them (which is why I gave some details and links about them in my answer).

Comment: @JasonLiam the dupes were not proposed to me by SO when I was typing the question. Usually I am happy to avoid dupes if I can but obviously a guy with little technical knowledge en detail of C++ but with a theoretical background *does not employ* the right terms to describe the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that `greater` is a function taking an unnamed (anonymous) `int` argument, and return a pointer to a function taking an `int` argument with the name `b`.

The part `(int b)` is the argument list for the *returned* function pointer.

To solve that specific problem use

```
bool (*greater(int b))(int)
```

instead.

Because function pointers are so complicated, they are usually hidden behind type-aliases:

```
using greater_function_type = bool(int);
greater_function_type* greater(int b) { ... }
```

---

As for the problem that lambdas with captures can't be used as C-style function pointers, use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as return type instead:

```
using greater_function_type = std::function<bool(int)>;
greater_function_type greater(int b) { ... }
```

Note that it's not returning a pointer anymore.

Since the C++14 standard you can use automatic return-type deduction with the keyword `auto`:

```
auto greater(int b) { ... }
```

If you need to store the returned objects, for example as a class member variable, you need to use `std::function<bool(int)>` for that.

---

Also be careful when using names like `greater` in conjunction with `using namespace std;` (which is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)), because of [`std::greater`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater).

Comment: Gahh! You got me there - I really goofed up the return value. Well done - in fact function pointers are so complicated that all other answers missed this second error :)). Time to brush up my C skills again - or convince mgmt to move to Rust.

Answer (score 3):

Lambda is capturing `[b]`, which cannot be converted to a function pointer. It requires `std::function`:

```
std::function<bool(int)> greater (int b) { ... }
```

If the function is expected to be `inline` then you may use simple `auto` as well:

```
auto greater (int b) { ... }
```

BTW, if `b` is not expected to change within the scope of `greater()`, then accept it as `const int b` instead f `int b` to be more expressive.

Answer (score 2):

In order to implement [**function currying**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), you need to use the computer-science concept of [**closure**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). One of the ways to achieve  it in C++ is using capturing lambdas (like you did in your code).

But only C++ lambdas **without capture** can be cast into a C style function pointer (as you attempted).
Lambdas with capture are actually classes with data members (one for each capture).
In your case you have one capture (`b`).

In order to return a **curried function** (which require a capture) you should use [**`std::function`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

std::function<bool(int)> greater(int b)
{
    auto l = [b](int v) { return v > b; };
    return l;

}

int main()
{
    auto g5 = greater(5);
    std::cout << g5(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << g5(7) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```